# Sql Server 2008: DBCC statement query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am migrating some codes from Sybase to Sql server 2008.In this process, I am executing below mentioned command-

`TRUNCATE TABLE [Table_name]`

`dbcc set_identity_burn_max([database_name],[Table_name], '0')`

but getting this error:

`Incorrect DBCC statement. Check the documentation for the correct DBCC syntax and options.`

Can anyone suggest me the correct syntax to run this code on sql server 2008r2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

`dbcc CHECKIDENT ('dbname', RESEED, 0)`

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx for documentation on how to use DBCC.

Note: do not try to use SQL Server like Sybase.

Comment: @Praveenks accepting the answer is Stack Overflow's way of saying "thanks" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Truncating the table should reset the seed as well...